# Computer with no registers

Tags: cpu-registers

I wasn't able to find an answer to my question anywhere on the web, so I thought stackoverflow would be my best bet! My question simply is, is it possible to establish a computer with no registers? I know registers are temp. data holders and provice the fastest way possible to access data, but what are the consequences to the inexistence of registers in a computer, besides making data transmission a lot slower?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine

Comment: I am curious why you need this type of architecture. Is it just a question out of general curiosity?

Comment: @TGH, a very similar question was on a quiz I'd recently taken. I knew it would be possible to have a computer with no registers. I just wanted to prove myself right since I haven't recieved a grade yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You *can* have a model of computation that doesn't involve registers. In fact, most theoretical models don't.

But as for a CPU, which is an electrical circuit, any kind of persistent state is implemented by a flip-flop, a.k.a. a register. There is no way to feed data into the circuits that perform processing without connecting a register to their inputs.

As for practical models of computation, i.e. instruction set architectures, you can avoid the terminology of calling anything a "register" but you inevitably need to define some means of data storage upon which operations act. Even if you don't, programmers will end up calling such storage locations as registers. Some old machines used the first page of RAM as primary scratch space, therefore the first 256 bytes were dubbed "registers," even if they were DRAM in the electronic sense. (Memory fails me; this could have been before DRAM. There is no difference between SRAM and what is physically called a register.)